# less than negative in R

Tags: r

How can I compare a column in `data frame` for range? The range is like less than a negative number and greater than a positive number. For Positive number there is no problem but for negative number it is taking it as an assignment operator.Code for reference is given below

```
Resited<-Reap[mean < -5 & mean > 5,]
```

Comment: As long as you have a space between the `<` and the `-`, you should be fine. Can you give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) where you actually have trouble? With about being able to run the same code and get the same error it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Do you mean `Resited<-Reap[mean < -5 | mean > 5, ]`? Otherwise it doesn't make much sense

Comment: This is either due to a typo or a complete misunderstanding of a logical-AND. Either way it should be closed as not reproducible or user-error (in thinking).

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes thats what i meant...

Comment: it keeps throwing the error "Error in mean < -5 : 
  comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Answer (score 4):

"mean" cannot be less than -5 and more than 5 at the same time. Did you mean logical OR? If both abs values are the same, you could simply write

```
Resited <- Reap[abs(mean) > 5, ]
```

Comment: fails if asymmetric as others have noted

Comment: True. I simply used topic-starter's numbers as an example.

Answer (score 3):

This simplest way in my opinion is just to put parentheses around your negative value:

```
Resited<-Reap[mean<(-5) | mean>5,]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case where your range is not symmetric around zero, `R` allows you to define your own operators:

```
`%between%` = function(x,range) x>range[1] & x<range[2]
-6 %between% c(-7,-2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This would appear not to answer the question asked, but could easily be modified to do so:   `x>range[1] | x<range[2]`  -- or just have the OP do  `x[ (!x %between% (c(upper,lower))]`